# YouTube videos all choppy

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, video, youtube, verizon, video-streaming

Has anyone seen this behavior when playing videos in the YouTube app?
I've tried clearing both the cache and data for the app, but it did not help.

Note in the screenshot how the video is all choppy and blocks that are all mixed up. 
It is happening on ALMOST all videos, but every rare one will work fine.

Running on a stock Verizon Galaxy S3.

[image]

Comment: Just for sake of trouble shooting, could you try another app other than Google's official app? For instance you may try "TubeMate".

Comment: Have you tried lowering the quality? Does this happen on both wifi and mobile data? Are there other programs running at the time?

Comment: I'll have to check some of those once I'm back on their phone. Will report back when I have answers.

Comment: Why don't you Disable the app once by clearing all the updates of YouTube and re-enabling (and updating) it again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. The only way I found to 'fix' it was to uninstall all updates back to factory defaults. So far that seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Tried this, uninstalling all the updates... and then reinstalled them, and then it worked perfectly. Played through a whole bunch of videos to make sure, and no issues on any of them. Woo! :)